# Blazor:: WASM:: diacritics normalize is not working properly when InvariantGlobalization is true

Tags: blazor, webassembly, diacritics

When InvariantGlobalization is true in csproj like below, HttpUtility.HtmlDecode values are not normalized properly. When InvariantGlobalization is false it is wokring fine.

<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
[image]

<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
[image]

Can you please suggest the solution for normalize the string when InvariantGlobalization is true?